# What is "taking gongs"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What is the meaning, if any, of the expression "taking gongs"?

I know what a gong is (a large Oriental cymbal).

But I don't understand the expression in the context of the following article: http://www.vanguardngr.com/2011/09/mad-men-modern-family-win-emmys-glory/

> LOS ANGELES (AFP) – Cult ad agency drama “Mad Men” won the best drama
>   Emmy for the fourth year late Sunday, while “Modern Family” again took
>   the comedy glory at US television’s awards show.
>
> British shows also triumphed at the annual Hollywood show, the Oscars
>   of the small screen, with Kate Winslet leading a string of Brits
>   **taking gongs**, notably for “Downton Abbey.”
>
> “Mad Men,” which has spawned a host of lookalike shows, fought off the
>   strongly-tipped “Boardwalk Empire” to take the best drama Emmy at the
>   climax of the show.

The expression only appears in the said article:
http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=%22taking+gongs%22&oq=%22taking+gongs%22 
so I am guessing is a typo of some sort...

or does it refer to another show?

Comment: As a replacement for a deleted answer, I should mention that this appears to have been written for a British English audience. An American reading this (depending on their age) would be much more likely to think of a performer getting gonged off the stage on talent shows like The Gong Show (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gong_Show). *Not* a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Gong* is a colloquial expression for an award or medal. The only citation I found for this was [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gong_(disambiguation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gong_%28disambiguation%29)

Answer (score 5):

*Gongs* is a slang term for military medals, dating from the 1940s if not earlier; both are suspended discs of metal.  And it's not far from that to 'prizes in general'.

Comment: In present usage, I don’t think *gong* is by any means restricted to military honours.  My first association of it is with the British honours lists — knighthoods, OBE’s, etc. — and my second association is with the Oscars.